# How to echo result errors instead of var dump

Tags: php, json

I am new to php just got a script which has var dump at the end of page
like this

```
var_dump($state);
```

after making post with:

```
$state = $postGenerator->broadcast($post);
```

I want to show "Your post has been made"  when var dump shows me [result] and show users the exact error which has happened once i see this with var dump

```
object(stdClass)#5 (2) { 
    ["error"]=> string(13) "invalid_grant"         
    ["error_description"]=> string(26) "The token has invalid role" 
}
```

I know this can be easy for many people here but i am just learning so your guide will be useful for me

Comment: `echo $state->error_description;`

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether `$state` has a `result` property, otherwise print the error message.

```
if (isset($state->result)) {
    echo "Your post has been made";
} else {
    echo $state->error_description;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help and saving life

Comment: once small help needed when i try to get back some info from post made like this echo $state->result["author"]  it gives me this error Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in.... can you please guide me if i need to call any of that, how i can thanks

Comment: It should probably be `$state->result->author` since `$state->result` is an object, not an array.